# Проблема с работой с файлами

Tags: python

Я хочу, чтобы когда пользователь нажимал "1", вводил имя и номер, они сохранялись в файле.
  С этим все ок, но когда я хочу создать еще одну запись в словаре, предыдущая удаляется.(Остаются только те, что записаны в коде изначально)
Также происходит, когда я вызываю просмотр всех контактов, показывает только "Мама" : "890878ччч07", "Папа" : "890878ччу07"
и последнюю запись, затем сразу удаляет последнюю запись

То есть суть в том, что программа не создает новую запись, а изменяет старую

```
ab = {  "Мама" : "890878ччч07",
        "Папа" : "890878ччу07"
}



print("Выберите действие:")
print("1)Добавить контакт")
print("2)Удалить контакт")
print("3)Просмотреть список всех контактов")
print("4)Изменить контакт")
print("5)Найти контакт")

act = input("Действие: ")




if act == "3":
    f = open("ab1.txt")
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if len(line) == 0:
            break 
        print(line, end='')
    f.close()






if act == "3)":
    f = open("ab1.txt")
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if len(line) == 0:
            break 
        print(line, end='')
    f.close()

if act == "Просмотреть список всех контактов":
    f = open("ab1.txt")
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if len(line) == 0:
            break 
        print(line, end='')
    f.close()

if act == "просмотреть список всех контактов":
    f = open("ab1.txt")
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if len(line) == 0:
            break 
        print(line, end='')
    f.close()


if act == "1":
    key = input("Введите имя: ")
    val = input("Введите номер: ")
    ab[key] = val


f = open('ab1.txt', 'w')
for key, val in ab.items():
    s = key + val + '\n'
    f.write(s)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо:

```
f = open('ab1.txt', 'w')
```

Вставьте:

```
f = open('ab1.txt', 'a')
```

`a` - добавление данных в файл

`w` - полная перезапись файла

Answer (score 0):

Все дело во втором аргументе метода open(). Когда мы передаем строку 'w' - файл открыт в режиме записи, в результате чего он заменяет старые данные новыми. для решения Вашей проблемы достаточно всего лишь заменить этот аргумент на 'a' (append, 'добавление')

```
f = open('ab1.txt', 'a')
```